# Inadvertently Set Macbook to Enforce Smartcard Login and Need to Bypass it

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, smart-card

PROBLEM: I set my Macbook Air (Late 2013/A1466/Big Sur) to "enforceSmartCard" to True (for testing) and thought I set it back to "False."

But seems I didn't.

So after rebooting, the computer started asking for a PIN at login after attempting to enter my password (as it should be, considering I set the property).

BUT...

There was NEVER a smartcard paired with the laptop, so there is NO PIN to be entered.

Also, the Smartcard PIN dialog doesn't even show up, even if there would be a PIN to use.

NB: This happened to be the problem I was trying to fix in the first place. A PIN dialog used to happen when inserting the smartcard into the reader when logging in to the organization's Citrix Access Gateway, but stopped completely after being hit or miss.

The smartcard was never paired with my laptop. The card and PIN are only used to access a virtual desktop via Citrix.

ATTEMPTED FIXES:

1. Swearing a lot at the computer -- Didn't work; didn't think it would.
2. Safe Mode -- Still asks for PIN.
3. Recovery Mode Terminal - can't run sc_auth or security smartcard commands.
4. Single User Mode - can't run sc_auth or security smartcard commands in SH, ZSH or BASH.
5. Target Mode - Tried connecting the current Intel Macbook to an M1 Macbook. When Intel Mac was in Target Mode, the M1 Mac couldn't see it (Thunderbold-USB C connection). Then I used instructions at: [Transfer Files Between Mac Silicon and Mac Intel](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchlb37e8ca7/14.0/mac/14.0). I could go into Recovery Mode with the M1 to start sharing the M1, but I can't get into the Intel Mac, so I'm SOL.
6. Recovery Mode OS Big Sur Reinstallation: Still asks for PIN.
7. Called Apple: The tech support advisor first said "it seems to a problem with your smartcard, so talk to the issuer." The smartcard worked (almost) fine before, and it was I who made the laptop enforce smartcard use.
8. Talked to the Support Supervisor: She tried to reach another team (Like Business and Education) but couldn't get through. She could only end up pointing me to the page that originally helped enable my derpitude. [Advanced smartcard options on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/advanced-smart-card-options-dep7b2ede1e3/web)

On a scale of 1 to [ImCompletelyAndTotallyHosed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/hosed), where am I? I find answers to smartcard problems on the interwebs IF you have access to the computer after logging in, which I can't.

Last option: Pull the drive and stick in an NVMe external drive case to hopefully access my user data (assuming I didn't faff that up, too), and the wipe the drive and do a clean OS install.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Thanks in advance!